# htaccess redirect index to public ignore css img and js

Tags: .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file in my server to rediect my subdomain website index folder to public.
However, after the redirection, css, js, img file all cannot be load.
How to fix it?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain.domain\.com.sg$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/subdomain.domain\.com.sg\/" [R=301,L]

DirectoryIndex public/index.php
```

Edited : 
I have update my htaccess file to this. 
the index file is loaded correctly, but can i remove the "public" from the url?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain.domain\.com.sg$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/subdomain.domain\.com.sg\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index.php$ subdomain.domain.com.sg/public/index.php [R=301,L]
```

sorry I am new to apache environment

Comment: That code will create an endless redirection loop. You redirect to exactly the same URL as was requested.

Comment: i just wan to redirect the subdomain.domain.com.sg/index.php  to subdomain.domain.com.sg/public/index.php

Comment: Ah, you changed the code, I assume you do _not_ get an endless redirection any longer?

Answer (score 0):

With "can i remove the "public" from the url?" you probably ask if you can internally rewrite incoming requests to the `/public` folder. Certainly you can. Question is if you want *only* that `index.php` file to be redirected or *all* requests beneath that. Note that these rules implement an *internal* rewriting, so do *not* alter the URL visible in the browser which is most likely what you want:

```
# http://subdomain.example.com/index.php => /public/index.php
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /public/index.php [L,QSA]
```

A more general approach:

```
# http://subdomain.example.com/foo/bar => /public/foo/bar
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you register `index.php` in your http servers host configuration as index document, then you can even drop that from the URL. Documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex:

```
# http://subdomain.example.com/ => /public/index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).